# npm command doesn't update json

Tags: node.js, json, npm, command-line

This command works fine:

```
json -I -f ./src/environments/build.json -e 'this.patch++'
```

I'm trying to create a custom build NPM command in my `package.json` file that runs this command before the actual build, but first I just tried to run the json command, just to see if it's working, but it doesn't :/

`package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "svrge-build-dev": "json -I -f ./src/environments/build.json -e 'this.patch++'",
    ...
  }
```

then I get this output (which is exactly the same as when I run the JSON code by itself) which means that the command is definitely running

```
> web-client@1.0.0 svrge-build-dev D:\repos\test\web-client
> json -I -f ./src/environments/build.json -e 'this.patch++

json: updated "./src/environments/build.json" in-place //<- this is exactly the same'
```

However, the `build.json` file is not being updated

No errors in the terminal

any idea how I can get it to work? I can't seem to find anything regarding that.

I would appreciate any help, been scratching my head for hours

Tom

Comment: What happens if you replace the single quotes with escaped double quotes, like  `json -I -f ./src/environments/build.json -e \"this.patch++\""`?

Comment: it works..... seriously. What would be the reason for this ? i got the code from their documentation with single quotes. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-stating what I said in the comment: try to replace the single quotes with double quotes:

```js
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        // ...
        "svrge-build-dev": "json -I -f ./src/environments/build.json -e \"this.patch++\"",
        // ...
}
```

What triggered that thought was this line in the output:

```
> json -I -f ./src/environments/build.json -e 'this.patch++
```

After doing some digging, I think it depends on the OS and/or command line interpreter. It shows the command that was run, but not with the finishing single quote.

After some searching, it appears that is indeed a bug: see [this issue](https://github.com/trentm/json/issues/117) and [this issue](https://github.com/trentm/json/issues/111). You might want to give the maintainers a heads up about it: the last issue I've linked to, makes it seem like it's a Windows issue.